# How to plot multiple lines based on index of the dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let us say we have a dataframe as under:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],[2012,2013,2014,2015,2012,2013,2014,2015]))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[10,20,10,30,50,20,60,80],
    'col2':[40,20,40,30,50,20,60,80],
    'col3':[10,20,80,30,80,20,80,10],
    },index=index)
```

I then added the names for these multi-index as 'Product' and 'Year' respectively.

Now I need to plot this data in such a way that for each 'Product' there is a different line **for a specific column**.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
df.plot(kind='line',x='Year')
```

I tried unstacking the dataframe using `unstack()`, however, as there are multiple columns, I will have to create as many new dataframes as there are columns for this to work.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can unstack:

```
df['col'].unstack(level=0).plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question about this unstack. Can you see if anything else works? I have too many columns instead of just one here.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. I'd say yes, unstacking for each column to get the plot is what I would do. You can also reset index and use seaborn's FacetGrid as well.