# How to plot line chart with lines from index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe I've already aggregated averages for, which are the columns nr_1, nr_2, etc.  They are grouped by a bin, which is also now the index.  How do I create a line plot where the lines are the index, and the X axis is nr_1, nr_2, etc.  basically nr_1, nr_2, etc. are months so I want those to be on x axis, but have the mean values as the y axis?  I can figure out how to change the x/y axis, but not how to make the index the individual lines.  Here is an excel picture of what I am trying to achieve and a snippet of the dataframe (this is in python by the way):

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022165/how-to-plot-multiple-lines-based-on-index-of-the-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transpose your dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.T.plot()
plt.legend(title='Bins')
plt.title('NR')
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]